# An idea to chain/attach two tables rows to each other

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am building an API which will handle to registers (in my case two tables) one **Receiving Register** and second **Dispatching Register**, as both are related with each other in some scenarios like a receiving register having a letter received from higher authorities and in this letter we need a response from other departments so we will dispatching the letter through dispatched register.

For this I have used pin_code in both the tables in receiving register I have kept it as an integer and updating it by one (n +=1) in each new record. while in dispatched register I have used the same field but made it optional with default value of "**0**" when I need to attach receiving table row to dispatched table row I just put the **pin_code** value from receiving register to this dispatched register **pin_code** field and it gives me the perfect solution.

Now my Actual question is that how  could I attach the same rows to each other with the same pin? 
Or  would I need to use **internal_pins** in both the tables to fulfil the requirements?

Any idea / Algorithm which reduce the time complexity as well as space  please?

Note : - I have find some related results in joomla etc in the shape of **Similar Posts or Similar Questions** i.e. here in the right side of **Stack Overflow website**...

[image]

Comment: Can you add some code? Like how your database actually looks and what results you're expecting? Maybe some code that you've tried yourself? Your story alone is not enough to understand what exactly you want. (at least to me)

Comment: If pin code is present in both table why it would be hard to merge similar rows by pin code?

Comment: pin_code is working fine for both the tables rows to connect to each other but i am not understanding that how i will attach records in the same table?

Comment: Check my answer if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I am still unsure of the requirement but here are my thoughts from what we have right now. Basically this will join those request with receiving records. Those that dont will have null fields for the Receiving columns

```
Select * from Dispatching d
left join
Receiving r
on d.pin_code=r.pin_code
```

If you want to see received register without dispatch record you can always use full join. But full join is not supported by mysql so youll probably need a union to replicate it.

Comment: Thanks for you quick response. I have no problem in printing the same. i need to know how to connect internal rows to each other.

Comment: Your question was "Now my Actual question is that how i could attach the same rows to each other with the same pin?". What do you mean by internal rows?

Comment: Specify the table designs and what output you wish to see.

Comment: sorry for ambiguity in the question. as you see that both the tables are connected via pin_code column and its working fine you know that, but what if i need to attach the rows in single (Same) table to each other? and for this purpose i think i will need to add one more column in both the tables like "enternal_pin" which will hold the pin_code for both the rows in the same table. example : table a row 2 is need to be connected to the table a row 4 for this i will need to save the same pin in enternal_pin and i hope it will help me to complete my aim.

Comment: Im sorry but i still do not get it. Can you please post your entire table design and can you explain the logic why you would need to join rows on the same table. I need the following information:

Table 1 Design and

Table 2 Design and

Expected Output